# Do Guice provider methods honor scope?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, guice

If I have a module like this:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(WhatsThis.class).to(AnAppleOfGold.class);
        bind(TellMeYourName.class).to(Bosse.class);
    }

    @Provides
    public AnAppleOfGold providesApple() {
        return new AppleOfGold(providesFizz());
    }

    @Provides
    public Bosse providesBosse() {
        return new Bosse("Grab a hold of my beard", providesFizz());
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public Fizz providesFizz() {
        return new Fizz(Math.random());
    }
}
```

Every time Guice uses `providesApple` and `providesBosse` to inject `AnAppleOfGold` and `Bosse` objects respectively, do they get the same singleton instance of Fizz? In other words, does Guice honor scope *between* provides methods, or does it only honor scope (in this case, `Scopes.SINGLETON`) from "outside" the module (the DI client code)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guice will honor Singleton scope between `@Provides` methods, *providing that Guice is the one calling them*.

In your example, you call `providesFizz()` manually, which works just like any other method call. Guice will inject a new instance each time you try to get a new `AnAppleOfGold` or `Bosse`. Meanwhile, it will create a separate new instance when you request a `Fizz` through Guice, and return that same instance for every `Fizz` injected through Guice.

So how do you access the common instance from other `@Provides` methods? Simple: Guice will [inject all parameters on your @Provides method](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods), including `Fizz` or `Provider<Fizz>`.

```
@Provides
public AnAppleOfGold providesApple(Fizz fizz) {
  return new AppleOfGold(fizz);
}

@Provides
public Bosse providesBosse(Provider<Fizz> fizzProvider) {
  return new Bosse("Grab a hold of my beard", fizzProvider.get());
}

@Provides @Singleton
public Fizz providesFizz() {
  return new Fizz(Math.random());
}
```